# Split a time into hours value, minutes value, and seconds

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, unix-timestamp

I have a file that contains `00:00:46` and I need to use `sed` or Awk to make 00, 00, and 46 their own variables to be compared to `date +"%H"`, `date +"%M"` and `date +"%S"`. How do I do this?

(i am using the dialog utility's timebox display that sends data to a tmp file to be read as: 00:00:00 (not zeros) and i have found no way of separating these inputs except `sed`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the shell's built-in token splitting.  Set `IFS` to the separator you want, then `set $value` to split the string in `$value` into `$1`, `$2`, etc.

```
# Split
value='00:45:33'
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=':'
set -- $value
IFS=$oldIFS

# Reap
echo hours: $1
echo minutes: $2
echo seconds: $3
```

Comment: Thanks @tripleee both for the edit and the answer ill try it out right now

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
hour=$(echo "00:00:46" | awk -F: '{print $1}')
minutes=$(echo "00:00:46" | awk -F: '{print $2}')
second=$(echo "00:00:46" | awk -F: '{print $3}')

echo "$second"
46
```